# Reading an AV asset from a pipe

Tags: ios, cocoa, posix, avfoundation, pipe

I am trying to coax AV Foundation to read from a mp4 file in memory (without using the intermediate write-to-disk solution).  I tried my own custom URL protocol and that failed since AV Foundation doesn't really use the URL loading system.  My next solution was to try to construct a POSIX pipe and have the AV Foundation layer load an asset from a named pipe file (i.e. from url "file:///path/path/.../path/mp4file.pipe") that was created with mkfifo().  This worked when trying to read the file via the usual fopen() calls but failed (with a crash) with the AVURLAsset initWithURL: call.

As anyone managed to get the AVFoundation to read from a pipe, or more generally, got the AVFoundation to work with mp4 files in memory?

Thanks.

Comment: @stackmonster: I can only find TSLibraryImport on github that deals with importing a users library from an iPod.  Do you have a link by any chance.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you able to be more specific?  I cannot seem to find any code that deals with loading from pipes or memory.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When reading an MP4 file, AVFoundation will use seeks which is why you obviously can't use a pipe.  I'm afraid your only options are really to either put the file to disk or use a small HTTP server and take advantage of HTTP Live Streaming.

Answer (score 1):

I used [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) for this purpose. It's a small, easily adapted HTTP server that basically sits in just one file.